# ASP MVC 4 globalizationScript, jquery and submitted data

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, globalization, unobtrusive-validation

im trying to use the following:

```
<script src="/Scripts/globalize.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
@Html.GlobalizationScript("~/Scripts/cultures/","~/Scripts/cultures/")
```

So unobtrusive client side validation works with the client culture, however, when data is posted to the server, it does not get 'translated' into the server culture as one would expect to. So whats the point of a working client side validation if it still wont work server side? Am i missing something? Any easy way to do this? Just like google chrome html 5 date picker, uses local date but translates it into server (or invariant) culture.

Answer (score 0):

Basically you need to synchronize the culture between server and client.

First you need to pass the server culture to the client. You could put this in your your view/layout HTML lang attribute:

```
<html lang="@System.Globalization.CultureInfo.CurrentUICulture.Name">
```

Another option is to put this information in a meta header

Once you have this information you need to initialize the client culture in Globalize.js by doing something like this:

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    // Set Globalize to the current culture driven by the html lang property
    var currentCulture = $("html").prop("lang");
    if (currentCulture) {
        Globalize.culture(currentCulture);
    }
});
```

And remember to include the right globalize.culture js file.

```
~/scripts/globalize/globalize.culture.xx-XX.js
```

More information [this post](http://icanmakethiswork.blogspot.co.uk/2012/09/globalize-and-jquery-validate.html) from John Reilly, explains it very well.